# laravel dompdf get base64 format

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, dompdf

I am using laravel-dompdf (Barryvdh\DomPDF) in a project and need to get the file in base64 format (vor a vue component)

In laravel controller:

```
$data = array(
  'values' => $documentValues
);

$pdf = PDF::loadView('documentTemplate', $data);
```

I can download the file using:

```
$pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

but I need a response from server with the source file in base64 format like this:

```
source: 'data:application/pdf;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_PDF>'
```

I have tried something like this:

```
base64_encode($pdf->stream())
```

but is not working.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I fixed:

```
return 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($pdf->stream());
```

Comment: "but is not working"  - what does that mean? If you could share more code, others could check why this is not working

Comment: @NicoHaase i fixed .... i  was only returned the base64_encoded without data:application.... :-)

Comment: You should submit solution as answer not add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Server side:

```
echo base64_encode($dompdf->output());
```

client side:

```
htmlstr['html'] = "<p>abcd</p>";
await axios.post(endpoint, transformToFormData(htmlstr), config, { responseType: 'blob' })

    .then(response => {
        if(response.status===200 && response.data != null ){
          console.log("response-data", response);
          const data = response.data;
          downloadPDF(data,fileName);
        
          
        }
      })
function downloadPDF(pdf,fileName) {
    const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it